# $P$ and $Q$ are the two vertices of a regular polygon having $12$ sides such that $PQ$ is a diameter of the circle circumscribing the polygon. Then...

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons

> **QUESTION:** Let $P=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $Q=(−\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},−\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ be two vertices of a regular polygon having $12$ sides such that $PQ$ is a diameter of the circle circumscribing the polygon. Which of the following points is not a  vertex of this polygon?
>
> (A) $(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}})$
>
> (B) $(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}})$
>
> (C) $(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}})$
>
> (D) $({-\frac{1}2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

---

**MY APPROACH:** If $P$ and $Q$ are the end points of the diameter, it is quite clear that the equation of the circle must be $$x^2+y^2=1$$ Therefore, all the vertices must lie on this circle. Now, checking from the options, we find that every point given in the options satisfies the above equation. Now I am stuck.

How else should I tackle the sum? Thank you in advance .

Comment: HINT: $360/12=30$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D)

But how did I get that answer? Well, firstly have you drawn a picture of the diagram, with angles labelled? If so, then you’ll notice that the arg (angle from the x axis) of any point on the polygon must be 15 mod 30. The last option doesn’t satisfy this property (the angle it forms is 120 degrees).

However, another approach is to notice — again from a well drawn diagram — that the figure is symmetric in the x axis, the y axis, and the x=y line. Since the first three options are just reflections of each other in these lines, the answer must be D. Meta analysis is useful in multiple choice!

Comment: Excellent work.. I just didn't think of the modulus! Although I loved the second approach more :P.. who does not love a logical shortcut ..

Comment: I think the last one forms $120°$ and not $150°$.. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Let find the cosine of the angle subtended by the point $P$ and each of the points in question, viewed from the center of the circle:

A) $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}},\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

B) $$\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

C) $$\frac12$$

D)$$\frac{-1+\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}$$

Could you draw the conclusion knowing that the central angle between adjacent vertices is $30^\circ$?

Comment: Did you use the formula $\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1.m_2}$?

Comment: Then the first one comes out to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ which is indeed $30°$..

Comment: I used only the formula explicitly shown for the case A), And I explained what I do in the preceding sentence. What you write is NOT a formula for cosine of an angle.

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong. It gives you the tangent angle..

Comment: Yes, whereas my formula immediately gives you the cosine of the angle.